# jQuery not recognizing Symfony JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json, symfony1

I'm trying to get my JSON data from Symfony but it doesn't seem to be working right. Below is the snippet of symfony code:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
return $this->renderPartial('listJsonResponse', 
array('jsonSlots' => json_encode($this->jsonQuery)));
```

The above works fine and hits the partial. All that is in my partial is this:

```
<?php echo $jsonSlots ?>
```

Now according to Firebug this gets populated properly. Below is a copy of the response

> [{"id":"1","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"2"},{"id":"2","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"3","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"4","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"5","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"6","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"7","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"8","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"9","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"10","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"11","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"12","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"13","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"14","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"15","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"16","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"17","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"18","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"19","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"20","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"21","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"22","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"23","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"24","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"25","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"26","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"27","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"28","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"29","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"30","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"31","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"32","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"33","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"34","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"35","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"36","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"}]

Note if I take out the Content/Type header it changes slightly. I get the same response tab as above but also an html tab with the above parsed into html. Which shows like this:

> [{"id":"1","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"2"},{"id":"2","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"3","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"4","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"09:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"5","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"6","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"7","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"8","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"10:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"9","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"10","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"11","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"12","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"11:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"13","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"14","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"15","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"16","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"12:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"17","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"18","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"19","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"20","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"13:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"21","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"22","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"23","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"24","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"14:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"25","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"26","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"27","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"28","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"15:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"29","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"30","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"31","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"32","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"16:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"33","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:00:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"34","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:15:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"35","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:30:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"},{"id":"36","schedule_day":"Mon","start_time":"17:45:00","concurrent_appointments":"2","currentCount":"0"}]

I know the JSON function is hitting, but it isn't parsing the success function and alerting me any sort of data. the JavasScript is shown below and is wrapped in a jquery ready tag

```
$.getJSON('/frontend_dev.php/module/listJSONSlots', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Any ideas why I can't get to the alert?

Comment: I don't know about Synfony and its renderPartial method. But clearly it replaces special characters by their `&...` equivalent. You should look for a way to disable this.

Comment: This is bang on the problem apparently. If you can post this as the answer I'll happily accept it. I used Symfony's renderText() attribute isntead and it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to render a template, you can skip that and directly return something from your action. Try this:

```
return $this->renderText(json_encode($this->jsonQuery));
```

Comment: Im trying to do the same thing but from a component - getting an error that renderText method is not defined ....

Comment: You only have renderText in actions, you do have to render a template in components. If you need the raw (unescaped) value of a variable, use `$sf_data->getRaw("varname")`.

Comment: You forgot to set the Content-Type to application/json.

Answer (score 2):

you need is to amend your partial

```
<?php $sf_data->getRaw('jsonSlots'); ?>
```

or use a simpler way from the actions

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
$this->renderText(json_encode($this->jsonQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_encode($input, true)` to force it to encode as an object.

Technically JSON's top-level container must be an object (enclosed with `{}`) and not an array (enclosed with `[]`).

The value of a property on a JSON object can be an array, but an array is not a JSON object.

Comment: Nope. Tried this and JSON_FORCE_OBJECT. It did change the syntax slightly but the alert still failed

Comment: No, that is not true. The top level can be an array: *A JSON text is a serialized object or array.* from [JSON's RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Synfony and its renderPartial method. But clearly it replaces special characters by their `&...;` equivalent. You should look for a way to disable this