# Call JavaScript Function from Symfony Component

Tags: php, javascript, symfony1

I have created a new JSON string (by converting a PHP array using `json_encode`) and stored it in `$siteTree` ... outputting it to the log shows the following

```
[
{
    "attr": {
        "id": "node_1",
        "rel": "folder"
    },
    "data": "New Title",
    "children": [
        {
            "attr": {
                "id": "node_2",
                "rel": "folder"
            },
            "data": "second document",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

]

So I know the JSON is formed correctly. What I am trying to do is use that variable in a javascript function to create an object using the JSON data ... I am doing the following in the template

```
<?php
    use_helper('JavascriptBase');
    echo javascript_tag('createTree('.$siteTree.')');
?>
```

The following is shown on the output page

```
createTree([{&quot;attr&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;node_1&quot;,&quot;rel&quot;:&quot;folder&quot;},&quot;data&quot;:&quot;New Title&quot;,&quot;children&quot;:[{&quot;attr&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;node_2&quot;,&quot;rel&quot;:&quot;folder&quot;},&quot;data&quot;:&quot;second document&quot;,&quot;children&quot;:[]}]}])
```

The function is called but the JSON has replaced the `"` with `&quote;`.  How can I stop this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you please show us `javascript_tag() ?`

Comment: Its a build-in symfony function

Comment: @DrMolle: It is a symfony function: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/JavascriptBaseHelper.php

Comment: Sorry - I have updated the post title ... also found this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763413/jquery-not-recognizing-symfony-json but im running this from a component and the renderText method is not available in a component

Comment: You have to be carful with terminology here. `json_decode` generates JSON, the way you currently insert it into JavaScript will make it a JavaScript object (actually an array in your case). I'm sure that is what you want, I just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: I wanted to pass the function JSON - i use the json_encode (not decode) .... home im doing it correct !

Comment: @ManseUK: Oops my mistake, of course I meant `json_encode`... so you are calling `JSON.parse` or something similar inside `createTree`?

Comment: Nope.  Perhaps that's my mistake ! But this error seems to be coming from symfony not the browser. That error is shown on the page not in the js console. I will see if I can alert the JSON string or parse it

Comment: No, it is fine. As I said, what you create via `json_encode` is a JSON string. But as you concatenate it with other JS code, it will be a JS object. Nothing wrong, I'm just nitpicky about terminology...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK .. So I managed to fix the problem ... this is how I did it ...I forgot about the json_encode and just passed an array up to the template of the component.

Within the template i processed it like this

```
echo javascript_tag('createTree('.json_encode($siteTree->getRawValue()).');');
```

This then output the correct JavaScript.

Thanks for everyones assistance ! Got there in the end

Answer (score 2):

Symfony automatically performs output escaping to help prevent several types of XSS attacks.

You can disable it by configuration, or depending on what version of the Symfony framework you're using, access the raw data in your view like this:

```
$sf_data->getRaw('siteTree')
```

e.g.

```
echo javascript_tag('createTree(' . $sf_data->getRaw('siteTree') . ')');
```

If that doesn't work for you, you should find the relevant references you need by consulting the Symfony documentation for your version of the framework, searching for "output escaping".

Comment: Now i get -> 
Notice: Undefined index: [{"attr":{"id":"node_1","rel":"folder"},"data":"New Title","children":[{"attr":{"id":"node_2","rel":"folder"},"data":"second document","children":[]}]}]

Comment: Considering I didn't give you any code that accesses an array, I think you will have to clarify where that error is coming from.

Comment: The variable $siteTree contains the first section of code in my post above. That was the resultif running Json_encode on an array